# Can I use Rive / Flare animations as downloadable Flutter assets?

Tags: flutter, flare, rive

I have a requirement for downloadable animations in a flutter app.  These animations will not be known at apk compile time so need to be downloaded.  I know it is possible to download image or sound files, unzip them to the users directory (getApplicationDocumentsDirectory) and display them.

Is it possible to download rive animations and show them or do the animations need to be compiled with the APK?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. Afterall, all we do is to provide path of .flr file. Without zip/unzip, it shouldn't be more than 10 lines of a code. Why not try and share the result.

Comment: Have you figured anything out about this? I have the same pressing question.

Comment: @Sukhi is it possible that you can explain exactly what you mean to a flutter new comer? Then this question will have an answer.

Comment: @atreeon, see https://blog.rive.app/rives-flutter-runtime-part-1/ - and see this part regarding their example:

"Note that we load raw bytes. This gives you flexibility in where you source your Rive data: as assets, over a network, from a local database, or by other means."